# Android Project Type

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on an Eclipse plugin for Android. In order to make the plugin controls only visible if the selected folder is a project I added

```
org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject
```

as object class in the plugin manifest. However, this makes the controls visible for any Eclipse project. Is there a possibility to make the plugin only visible for Android projects? I did not find an interface like IAndroidProject.

Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the type is always IProject but you can use natures instead.